# Json Structure Issue

Tags: asp.net, json.net

A third party API is returning JSON in the following format

```
{
"group1": {
    "Colour": "Blue",
    "Name": "Dave"
},
"group2": {
    "Colour": "Red",
    "Name": "Karen"
},
"group3": {
    "Colour": "Green",
    "Name": "Ryan"
 }
}
```

I'm finding the outer 'groupX' identifier to problematic when attempting to deserialize the JSON using JSON.NET.

Does anyone know best to parse JSON in this format?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "employees": [
        { "first-name":"John" , "last-name":"Doe" },
        { "first-name":"Anna" , "last-name":"Smith" },
        { "first-name":"Peter" , "last-name":"Jones" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AmalaBalaji but unfortunately I cannot change the format of the JSON

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, "how to best parse the JSON in this format?"

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is Correct.
if tou want to check than use below url [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Define a class `Group` like this:

```
class Group
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Group>>(json);
```

Here's a quick demo:

```
string json = @"
{
""group1"": {
    ""Colour"": ""Blue"",
    ""Name"": ""Dave""
},
""group2"": {
    ""Colour"": ""Red"",
    ""Name"": ""Karen""
},
""group3"": {
    ""Colour"": ""Green"",
    ""Name"": ""Ryan""
 }
}";

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Group>>(json);
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    Group group = kvp.Value;
    Console.WriteLine("  Colour: " + group.Colour);
    Console.WriteLine("  Name: " + group.Name);
}
```

Output:

```
group1
  Colour: Blue
  Name: Dave
group2
  Colour: Red
  Name: Karen
group3
  Colour: Green
  Name: Ryan
```